# How to shade geonode-animated mesh with mid-graph location attribute?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, geometry

Using geometry nodes, I set up hexagons to move up and down in a sine wave pattern as the scene moves through time. Then, I added noise as an offset, to vary the hexagons' height as they move up and down the sine wave. When assigning color to the material, I'd like the color to come from the hexagons' height, but only their heights from before I added the noise offset in the geometry nodes graph. Right now in the shader nodes editor, the "Object Info" node's Location value is outputting the final location, after the geometry is offset by noise. Can I get the pre-noise location to drive my shader color?

Edit: Capture attribute doesn't seem to be working the same way as one answer shows. I'm posting screenshots and my file for reference. I'm using Blender 3.1 :
[image]

[image: Geometry Nodes]
[image: Shader Nodes]
[image: Material Preview]

Comment: Try to use Transfer Attribute node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this node setup does what you want:

[image]

shader setup:

[image]

modifier:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

to answer the question in the comment, how to setup the shader that the top part is white and the bottom part black:

[image]

you can use a colorramp and the generated texture coordinate z for that. Together with a math node (greater than) you can determine which color should be chosen.

You have to mute the "realize instances" node in GN to make that work.

--- UPDATE on next comment:

you can use this shader node setup:

[image]

and adapt the GN node tree like this:

[image]

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried using your same node setup using Capture Attribute, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using Blender 3.1. Instead of using noise, I'm using an empty whose Z transform is baked from sound files (for music visualization). Perhaps I should upload my file?

Comment: If you want me to take a look : yes

Comment: Much appreciated. I edited my original question with three screenshots of my setup, as well as a blend-exchange link to my file.

Comment: you have set the output to instance, set both to point and it works [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHcz2.jpg [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl5Ko.png if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left to my answer. thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! One last thing I wanted to ask is, is there a way for the color of each hexagon to vary along it's height? As in, if the center of a hexagon prism was at z = 0, could the top part (where z > 0) be in one color like white, while the bottom part (z < 0) be in black?

Comment: so you now want the color to be constant and should not change anymore over time, did i understand you right?

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: I apologize, I should've been more clear. I would like to keep the varying color over time, but instead of each hexagon being a single uniform color between the two colors of the color ramp, the individual hexagons also have a smooth gradient along the z axis. Edit: perhaps to put another way, even individual meshes have smooth color gradation to go along with the overall color ramp from top most hex to bottom most hex

Comment: i updated my answer again. Please do not ask more questions in comments. Please open a new question so everybody with same problems can learn and get help from them. You can ask as many questions as you want - but please - don't ask in comments. Thanks